# JQuery Sortable with Scrolling

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

With jQuery sortable, I have a very long list which forces a scrollbar. Whenever it is long enough to do this, every time I grab an item, the page automatically starts scrolling and the LI jumps way off my cursor. It works perfectly whenever I'm using a shorter list. Any help?

Current LI CSS:

```
min-height: 60px;
margin-top: 12px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
padding: 10px 10px 15px 10px;

background: #FAFAFA;

.roundCorners(3px);
.boxShadow(0,4px,10px,#222);

border: 1px #D4D4D4 solid;
```

Current jQuery:

```
    var makeNotesSortable = function () {
        $("#notes").sortable
        ({
            update: function () {
                console.log($("#notes"));
                updateNoteOrder($("#notes"));
            }
        }).disableSelection();
    }
```

[image: The LI to move jumps way off the cursor]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to this issue, but I turned scrolling off and set the axis to 'y' only.

```
        $("#notes").sortable
        ({
            scroll: false,
            sort: function (event, ui) {
                ui.helper.css({ 'top': ui.position.top + $(window).scrollTop() + 'px' });
            },
            helper: 'clone',
            axis: 'y',
            update: function () {
                updateNoteOrder($("#notes"));
            }
        }).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 2):

@Kerry Ritter's answer is the right way to fix the problem But don't forget 
to modifiy your CSS for the #sortable element by adding:

```
position: relative;
```

Answer (score 1):

Debug the first drag !

```
jQuery(".sortable").sortable({

    axis: "y", 
    containment: "parent",
    scroll: false,
    handle: ".handle",
    tolerance: "pointer",

    create: function (event, ui) {
        this.first_drag_debug = true;
    },
    sort: function (event, ui) {
       if ( this.first_drag_debug == false ) {
         ui.item.css( 'top', ( ui.position.top + jQuery(window).scrollTop() ) + 'px');
       }
    },
    change:function(event, ui){
        this.first_drag_debug = false;
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){ 
        this.first_drag_debug = false;
    },
    update: function(){ 
        update(); 
    },

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make container scrollable itself, not a page body or any other parent, then scroll position will be calculated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but this is how I was able to solve the issue with multiple scrolling elements on a page:

```js
$("ul.reorder").sortable({ 
    axis: 'y',
    containment: 'parent',
    tollerance: 'pointer',
    cursor: 'move',
    sort: function(event, ui) {
        var $target = $(event.target);
        if (!/html|body/i.test($target.offsetParent()[0].tagName)) {
            var top = event.pageY - $target.offsetParent().offset().top - (ui.helper.outerHeight(true) / 2);
            ui.helper.css({'top' : top + 'px'});
        }
    }
});
```